# Retrieving data from array of objects in json (Angular)

Tags: arrays, json, angular, object, parsing

I have the folowing JSON file

```
    {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": "1111",
    "method": "object-define",
    "params": [
        {"type": "FEEDBACK","component": "AUDIO", "object": "BUTTON", "id": "1", "state": "ACTIVE"},
        {"type": "FEEDBACK","component": "AUDIO", "object": "BUTTON", "id": "2", "state": "ACTIVE"}
    ]
}
```

and am trying to get the 'type' of an object.
Using the following code I'm able to return an object.
However selecting the 'type' or 'component' for example is not possible.

```
example_protocol = require("../../assets/example_protocol.json");

    this.serialSplitted = JSON.stringify(this.example_protocol, ['params']);
    this.serialParams = JSON.parse(this.serialSplitted);
    this.serialObjects = this.serialParams.params;
    console.log(this.serialObjects[0]);
```

Thought of using

```
console.log(this.serialObjects[0].type);
```

or

```
console.log(this.serialObjects[0]['type']);
```

But keeps getting 'undedfined'

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```js
var example_protocol = {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": "1111",
    "method": "object-define",
    "params": [
        {"type": "FEEDBACK","component": "AUDIO", "object": "BUTTON", "id": "1", "state": "ACTIVE"},
        {"type": "FEEDBACK","component": "AUDIO", "object": "BUTTON", "id": "2", "state": "ACTIVE"}
    ]
}

    var serialSplitted = JSON.stringify(example_protocol);
    var serialParams = JSON.parse(serialSplitted);
    var serialObjects = serialParams.params;
    console.log(serialObjects[0]);
    console.log(serialObjects[0].type);
```

you do not need to use `['params']` during `JSON.stringify`

Comment: This works!! Thank you very much, was breaking my head for hours :)

Comment: Happy to help :-)